# htaccess how to support '/' have or haven't

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)/$ user.php?name=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)/([^\/]*)/$ user.php?name=$1&a=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)/([^\/]*)/([^\/]*)/$ user.php?name=$1&a=$2&id=$3 [L,NC]
```

My web site maybe 3 url format.

```
1. http://www.domain.com/user.php?name=tom
   http://www.domain.com/user.php?name=mary
   etc....

2. http://www.domain.com/user.php?name=tom&a=v
   http://www.domain.com/user.php?name=tom&a=photo
   etc....

3. http://www.domain.com/user.php?name=tom&a=v&id=9889
   http://www.domain.com/user.php?name=tom&a=photo&id=123
   http://www.domain.com/user.php?name=tom&a=data&id=123
```

Basically, there are only three values
I want url to be 301 url rewrite to `domain.com/a/b/c/`

These htaccess code is ok. but not perfect.

**test1 :**

not work
http://www.domain.com/tom    to->   http://www.domain.com/user.php?name=tom

work
http://www.domain.com/tom**/**   to->  http://www.domain.com/user.php?name=tom

**test2 :**

not work
http://www.domain.com/mary/v    to->  http://www.domain.com/user.php?name=mary&a=v

work
http://www.domain.com/mary/v**/**   to-> http://www.domain.com/user.php?name=mary&a=v

**test3** :

not work
http://www.domain.com/kate/photo/123  to-> http://www.domain.com/user.php?name=kate&a=photo&id=123

work
http://www.domain.com/kate/photo/123**/**  to-> http://www.domain.com/user.php?name=kate&a=photo&id=123

I want user type the url more user friendly or more free

**so, How to let them to work?? The user can type '/' or not, the same can succeed**

http://www.domain.com/tom

http://www.domain.com/mary/v

http://www.domain.com/kate/photo/123

Anyone can give me some suggest? Or more clever code?

More one url rewrite question...   htaccess can set these link if haven't '/' auto add '/' ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the question mark quantifier `?` matches an occurrence of zero or one. Which is essentially 'The user can type '/' or not'

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/?$ user.php?name=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/?$ user.php?name=$1&a=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/?$ user.php?name=$1&a=$2&id=$3 [L,NC]
```

Note: this is not SEO friendly, because you are providing two urls for the same content.

If you don't want the user to be wrong when he types the forward slash, then you should redirect them to the non-forward slash url instead of serving them the content on that url.

**EDIT:**

> But if user use not '/' come my site. can I use htaccess to send them to use '/'?

This Redirects the user from non trailing slash url to, urls with trailing slash

```
# add trailing slash, when not present
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# notice the ? is gone
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/$ user.php?name=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/$ user.php?name=$1&a=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/$ user.php?name=$1&a=$2&id=$3 [L,NC]
```

This is off the top of my head, so give it a try and let me know if it works

Comment: I have try your code. can display website. but lose the $_GET['value']. php can't get the $_GET[a] and $_GET[name]

Comment: did you wrap `/?` in parenthesis?

Comment: about SEO, can I set something like to this? RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Thanks, Jay. I don't wrap.  just this 3 rows and row1 : RewriteEngine on  

-----row2:RewriteBase /

Comment: Try to change `*` to `+`. But i don't see why this wouldn't work for you.

Comment: @Sky: in PHP, use: `$_GET["name"]` and `$_GET["a"]` with `""`.

Comment: Jay, RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)/+$ user.php?user=$1   work and can get the $_GET.  but if not '/' will be 404error

Comment: Croises, yes I using, Thanks

Comment: Jay, thanks a lot. added about %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} that's OK now.

But if user use not '/' come my site. can I use htaccess to send them to use '/'?

Comment: Try the edit, its off the top of my head. let me kno what you get

Comment: I used your version1(^([^\/]+)/?$) and 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]  this 2 rows.

everything is OK.

Comment: Jay. Thanks again. You reply for me, I'm very grateful. Everything OK now.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)$ $1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+/[^\/]+)$ $1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+/[^\/]+/[^\/]+)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/?$ /user.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/?$ /user.php?name=$1&a=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/?$ /user.php?name=$1&a=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

With one `/` before `user`

Comment: Thanks, I try it. But ERROR 500. The htaccess just this 4 rows

Comment: Did you copy/paste all this .htaccess code and use only that ?

Comment: I using the new update. That's work ! perfect for me !thank you very much !

Comment: Yes you have to use that, to avoid use with user.php and others

Comment: Croises, Thanks again. But if user use not '/' come my site. can I use htaccess to send them to use '/'?

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks Croises!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66498/discussion-between-sky-and-croises).